# "Member ' Class1.GetChar(string, int)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to return the Char value representing the character from the specified index in the supplied string.But error happens.

I've tried on Visual Studio.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static char GetChar(string str, int a)
        {
            return str[a];
                }
    }
}


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            var result = class1.GetChar("abcdef", 4);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to use the function, it shows error : "Member ' Class1.GetChar(string, int)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;qualify it with a type name instead." I don't know how to adjust.

Comment: `GetChar` is a `static` method and should be called against the type (`Class1.GetChar(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

On the method 'GetChar' you have the static modifier. 
This means the method is not used by an instance of Class1, but just Class1 itself.

So you must call this method by saying Class1.GetChar("abcdef", 4), you cannot call this method with an instance of Class1.

To elaborate a bit further, Your error says: "Class1.GetChar(string, int)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead."

The variable you create (class1) is an **instance** of **Class1**.
**Class1** is a **Type**.
So where it says "qualify it with a type name instead" it means you must use the type name (Class1) not an instance of the desired type.

Comment: @Siren Why do you expect it to display anything? You're not writing anything. `return` means that the method returns a value to the caller. In your case, this value is stored in `result`. Nowhere do you write it. Try `Console.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: @John Thanks!! I just found the way and deleted my previous comment, sorry

Comment: Of course the other solution would be to make the method non-static so it can be called with an instance.